# iOS IAP Subscriptions: Schedule 2 (Section 3.8(b))

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, review

I recently submitted my app for review & received the below rejection for the third time. I am not sure what this means anymore & would like any help the forum can provide.

---

We noticed that your App did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b).

Your app did not include:

- Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
- Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
- The account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
- Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
- Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable

Next Steps :

Please revise your app to include the missing information. Adding the above information to the Store Kit modal alert is not sufficient; the information must also be listed somewhere within the app itself, and it must be displayed clearly and conspicuously.

If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it.

---

I have the following already in place:

1. I have updated the App description on the app store with the above terms and conditions in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b).
2. The Privacy Policy and Terms of Use links are clearly present on the Subscriptions purchase page

I notice that my In-App Purchases on ItunesConnect are also in "Developer Action Needed" status. Here are a few things I can think of to avoid another rejection.

1. The Subscriptions in the app have a "Buy" button next to them. Should I be changing those button texts to "Subscribe" to better indicate they are subscriptions?
2. In the In-App Purchases, the Localization for English has a red mark beside it. I can update the IAP description to include all the text that Schedule 2, Section3.8(b) demands. Would that be the reason the IAPs in iTunesConnect is in "Developer Action Needed" status?
3. Should I change my app UI to show all the terms mentioned in Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b)?

"
1. You get 30 free workouts when you initially download the app. Thereafter you have a variety of subscription options available inside the app.

2. Any subscription option will give you an unlimited number of workouts for the subscription duration
3. Payment will be charged to iTunes account at confirmation of purchase
4. Your subscription will automatically renew unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours prior to the end of the current period
5. Your account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
6. Your subscriptions can be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user’s Account Settings after purchase.
7. No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during the active subscription period
8. Any unused portion of the free workouts will lapse once you purchase any subscription.
9. Privacy Policy link goes here
10. Terms of Use link goes here.
    "
    Any direction from the community will be really helpful.

Thank you

Comment: It turned out that the policy has apparently changed. I added a UIAlert on click of the Buy button which displayed the terms and requesting a Confirm/Cancel response and then triggering the StoreKit Buy process.That got the app through the gates!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes these app reviewers are not very cut and dried. They are humans not computers. They have different perspectives, understandings, experience levels; they make mistakes.

I submitted an app this year (2020) with in app subscriptions, and it got rejected for a bogus reason. I submitted it for review again without changes and put in a response stating how they were wrong. After that the app was accepted.

The reviewers could be people under pressure, and with daily targets, or targets amongst themselves etc. It's very annoying that they are not surgical with the reviews and detailed with the feedback. The feedback information is always template like and usually useless. Your app could just have been reviewed by a lazy person or someone incompetent. Yes it's apple, but they are still normal human beings.

Conclusion: if you are convinced you are correct with your submission, submit the app again and explain yourself in the response section. While waiting, submit a Developer Help request, and hopefully they will be able to point out where the issue is, if any.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the policy has apparently changed. I added a UIAlert on click of the Buy button which displayed the terms and requesting a Confirm/Cancel response and then triggering the StoreKit Buy process.That got the app through the gates!

Comment: @Mihir How the popup needs to show. After click on the buy it shows the details. The privacy url already available in the settings. Shall i need to add agan in the pusrchase screen

Answer (score 3):

Jacob Eiting write a [fine post](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/apple-will-reject-your-subscription-app-if-you-dont-include-this-disclosure-bba95244405d) about this problem. The main point is just add following text in subscription view

> A [purchase amount and period] purchase will be applied to your iTunes
> account [at the end of the trial or intro| on confirmation].
> Subscriptions will automatically renew unless canceled within 24-hours before the end of the current period. You can cancel anytime
> with your iTunes account settings. Any unused portion of a free trial
> will be forfeited if you purchase a subscription.
> For more information, see our [link to ToS] and [link to Privacy Policy].

And duplicate this information in app store description